# How to access a value from a dictionary within a dictionary to use in a formula

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary like such:

```
tfDic = {
    '/home/seb/Learning/ex17output.txt': {
        'COOL': 1,
        'FILE': 1,
        'FUN': 1,
        'HAVE': 1,
        'STUFF': 2
     }
 }
```

I tried to access the value of 'COOL' by doing this:

```
def tf(file, word):
    return tfDic[file][word]
```

but I got a `KeyError`. Afterwards I tried:

```
tf = tfDic[file].values()[term]
```

but I get:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str
```

Comment: your first option should works, can you check your file name

Comment: How did you *call* `tf`; what values for `file` and `word` did you supply? It works fine for me (once the typo is fixed). `values()` in the second version gives you a list e.g. `[1, 2, 1, 1, 1]`, which you can't index into with `'COOL'`.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I called tf with a loop so that the file feeds in from a list and the word is supplied, i.e. `tf(file, 'COOL')` both of them should be (and are) there, it is the `COOL` that throws the Error, and it is clearly there

Comment: Could you please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that allows others to recreate the error?

Answer (score 1):

funny, works for me.

```
>>> tfDic = {
...     '/home/seb/Learning/ex17output.txt': {
...         'COOL': 1,
...         'FILE': 1,
...         'FUN': 1,
...         'HAVE': 1,
...         'STUFF': 2
...      }
...  }
>>> def tf(file, word):
...     return tfDic[file][word]
... 
>>> 
>>> tf('/home/seb/Learning/ex17output.txt','COOL')
1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you got a `KeyError`, that means either your `file` or `word` did not match. Print out the values, or check them in the debugger. Your dictionary simply doesn't contain the values you provide.

Comment: the file is fed from a list so it has to be there, the KeyError jumps out for the word, which also is 100% there

Answer (score 0):

I just recognised a flaw, not all of the sub dictionaries have the same words...

yup I'm dumb, ty for trying to help